# Cómo acceder a un elemento de una estructura de registros y datos?

Tags: jquery

Cargo un valor en un input de un formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
$(this).find("td:eq(1)").find("input").val(valor)
```

Dicho valor puede ser modificado por el usuario. Lo que no sé es cómo obtener el valor de dicho input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer asi:

```
var valor = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").find("input").val();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias "alanfcm" por la solución aportada; funcionó bien.